# Hibernate Criteria issues a deprecation warnings

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm getting the warning:

`Positional parameter are considered deprecated; use named parameters or JPA-style positional parameters instead.`

with a `Criteria` object (`Restrictions` class). How do I add a parameter to the criteria when the Criteria  object doesnt seem to have an `Criteria::setString`.

Here is my criteria:
`criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("userId", 1);`

Comment: Are you sure that the warning is coming from that line : criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("userId", 1); ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right I deleted this line and the warning is still here. It was caused by the use of posistionnal parameter `?` in  a `@NamedQuery` (inside the `@Entity`) which seems to be deprecated in Hibernate 4.